# Why is there only 1 data when I pull from Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

As Future, I draw data from the firebase by looking at the ownerID. I didn't use a stream. Although there are 2 data in Firebase, there is only one data coming and I do not understand why.

```
class FireStoreService{
  FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<QuerySnapshot> getEvents({String uid}){
    return _db.collection("events").where("ownerID",isEqualTo: uid).get();

  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

{eventDesc: Merhaba Bu saatte ilacını içmelisin, addTime: Timestamp(seconds=1615410000, nanoseconds=0), listOfDay: [Salı], eventTime: Timestamp(seconds=1615582800, nanoseconds=0), ownerID: JRqTkH2fzzcmP3mB90j0ahJVeLp1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QuerySnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) has only one property [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/docs.html), which is a List of Document Snapshots.

**Access that to get all the results**

So, try changing your code to

```
class FireStoreService{
  FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot class>> getEvents({String uid})async {
    final QuerySnapshot snapshot = await _db.collection("events").where("ownerID",isEqualTo: uid).get();
    return snapshot.docs;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?